# Unable to trigger shell script from azure repo through pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cloud, devops

I have deploy.sh file in my azure repository and i need to execute this deploy.sh file from azure pipeline.

[image]

Here is the steps that i defined in pipeline. I tried two ways to do it through cmd and bash, both are not picking the right location of deploy.sh file

[image]

Here is the error i am getting:

This is the error from CMD, but CMD shows green even though path is not correct

[image]

This is the error for bash

[image]

**Question**

How to correct the path and do successful execution of deploy.sh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue

```
  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: |
        echo Write your commands here
        cd $(Build.Repository.Name)/Orchestration/dev/
        chmod +x deploy.sh
        ./deploy.sh      
        echo deploy.sh execution completed
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never hard code the path of the pipeline run. Instead you should use the predefined variables that will automatically pick the build ID and also path. For your case you will need the

```
$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/Orchestration/dev/deploy.sh
```

If you have multiple repositories checkout you should also use the name of the repository like

```
$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/dotnetpipeline/Orchestration/dev/deploy.sh
```

`$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s` should be also replaced by `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`

The predefined variables should follow the `$(var)` notation on the .YML file

Comment: /home/vsts/work/_temp/43f1bf3c-8d27-476b-aa8b-87f74e2239ed.sh: line 3: /home/vsts/work/1/s/dotnetpipeline/Orchestration/dev/deploy.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: ##[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/vsts/work/1/s/Orchestration/dev/deploy.sh'

Comment: - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: |
        echo Write your commands here
        
        $(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/dotnetpipeline/Orchestration/dev/deploy.sh
        echo deploy.sh execution completed
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      filePath: './Orchestration/dev/deploy.sh'
      workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s'

Comment: I modified like above ang got error for cmd and bash

Comment: If you do not have multiple repositories checkout use `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/Orchestration/dev/deploy.sh`

Comment: I have multiple repositories :(

Comment: Do you checkout all the repositories? I have provided options for both many repositories and one repository. As it seems from the steps you checkout only the current

Comment: how do i do that , i am new in this area, please help

Comment: steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: DockerCompose@0

Comment: This is what i am doing to checkout

Comment: You can remove the checkout task it will automatically do that. In this `bash` task you should use `filepath: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/dotnetpipeline/Orchestration/dev/deploy.sh'` and remove the working directory

Comment: ##[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/vsts/work/1/s/dotnetpipeline/Orchestration/dev/deploy.sh''

Comment: i foudn this also

Comment: resources: 
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/main

Comment: Try to combine your comments in larger comments as the thread is becoming large. try `filepath: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/Orchestration/dev/deploy.sh'` or `filepath: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/dotnetpipeline/Orchestration/dev/deploy.sh'`

Comment: ##[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/vsts/work/1/s/dotnetpipeline/Orchestration/dev/deploy.sh''                        
 ##[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/vsts/work/1/s/Orchestration/dev/deploy.sh' Error still

Comment: Thanks for the help, i am upvoting every help... i managed to fix this , i added as answer